# After axios call, how should I update the front-end? [I have 2 ways]

Tags: reactjs, state, axios

I have an array of todos. When I delete one of them, I succesfully delete it also from the database with DELETE call. However, I am not sure how to update the front-end. First way is changing the state by deleting the related todo.

```
onDelete(todo) {
    axios.delete('api/todos/' + todo.id).then(res => {
        var array = [...this.state.todos]; // make a separate copy of the array
        var index = array.indexOf(todo)
        array.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({todos: array}); // other state elemenets other than todos will not be affected
    });
}
```

Other way is, making a new axios GET request to get all the todos from the database. (this will be an axios request inside an axios request)

```
onDelete(todo) {
    axios.delete('api/todos/' + todo.id).then(res => {
        // make an axios get request on api/todos
        // then, set state with data in response.
    });
}
```

Hence, which one is the better approach?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be the second one, to call a get request once more. So that no matter what the change database has undergone, the UI will be an exact replica of the data from db instead of manually changing(deleting in this case) the list from UI. However there will be the delay of api response for UI updation in this case.

Comment: To avoid the delay it's also possible to do both. First remove the item by directly changind the state, then call the get method to make sure the state is corresponding to the database by using `get`

Comment: Yes, but if the api response is fast enough, it would be an unnecessary object comparison and deletion of objects from ui and if there is actually change between data from api and currently in state , then restoring the item, such level of complications would be hectic to manage.

Comment: I fail to see the complexity. You just set the state (well, twice) and let React do the rest. If the state changes - the item will as well. If you want to be a little more efficient you can compare the response from the server with the current state and set it only if they aren't the same, still simple enough.  <br> I do agree that it probably won't be necessary in most cases, as the response really shouldn't take that long.

Comment: The complexity comes when you have to handle a case when u delete an object from ui/state and then the api does have that value, then you will have to handle a case where you have to restore the item to the ui/state where the end user will have no idea how this thing came back!

Comment: What will happen is either a swift -item disappears-item reappears, or just no visible visible change (if the response from the server was fast enough). Not ideal - true, but not very different (or any different) from the alternative in which you only update the state by setting it to the response value from the server. If the item reappears, it means the deletion process was not successful, and that's an outcome that needs to be handled either way.

Comment: Yes, so i would still say instead of going for an inconsistent behaviour like that(if the api delays, the item disapearing and appearing wont be swift) the safest bet would be to go with simple get request and update the ui using this response, quickest easiest and safest method.

Comment: True, but if the response delays letting the client just hang isn't all that great. I'd probably go with adding that item with a loader widget by explicitly changing the state, and then have that loader disappear (or change into v/x ) when the response from the server returns

Comment: But a progress bar(which disapearing like a swish ;) ) is a waiting period but an inconsitent behaviour is a sure irritation.

Comment: I don't see any inconsistent behavior in the suggestion in my last comment, nor the need to keep the user until the database is updated (again, in the off case it might take a while) instead of just having it updating the task status (think for example how messages in Whatsapp work)